# Speak out on ImageButton Click

Tags: android, android-imageview, onclicklistener, android-dialog

I did implement a gridview having Imageviews as its items and onClick on any of these items, a custom dialog box pops up to give a brief description of the image as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352717/custom-dialog-boxes-to-show-image-text-and-settitle).

In the dialog box, there's just one button which closes the dialog box on click. However, I was wondering how the code and login would be if I were to add a second button to the dialog box and speak out the image name on click on that second button.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you should do this

in your adapter of your list view set the content description of your imageview and on the click of your second button

use imageview.getContentDescription ----this returns you a charsequence so speak it using android TextToSpeech engine using the speak method in it...

like this

```
TextToSpeech tts=new TextToSpeech(this,this) //first for context and other for the onInitListener
```

now use the speak method..

```
tts.speak
```